# Python: How to write error in the console in txt file?

Tags: python

I have a python script which every 10 minutes sends me an email with everything written in the console. I am running this with the crontab in my ubuntu 18.04 vps.
Sometimes it doesn't send the mail so I assume that when an error happens execution stops but how can I get the errors to be written in a txt file so I can analyze the error ?

Comment: Write to a log file by using the logging package.

Comment: What code are you using? Can't you just wrap it in a `try` and save the exception in the `catch`?

Comment: `logging` is the preferred way to do this. If you are feeling sufficiently diabolical, you can pass a file handle object to `print` with the `file` kwarg

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both; you should probably expect answers to cover Python 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Logging Module

To demonstrate the approach with the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) module, this would be the general approach

```py
import logging

# Create a logging instance
logger = logging.getLogger('my_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # you can set this to be DEBUG, INFO, ERROR

# Assign a file-handler to that instance
fh = logging.FileHandler("file_dir.txt")
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO) # again, you can set this differently

# Format your logs (optional)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter) # This will set the format to the file handler

# Add the handler to your logging instance
logger.addHandler(fh)

try:
    raise ValueError("Some error occurred")
except ValueError as e:
    logger.exception(e) # Will send the errors to the file
```

And if I `cat file_dir.txt`

```
2019-03-14 14:52:50,676 - my_application - ERROR - Some error occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: Some error occurred
```

### Print to File

As I pointed out in the comments, you *could* accomplish this with `print` as well (I'm not sure you will be applauded for it)

```py
# Set your stdout pointer to a file handler
with open('my_errors.txt', 'a') as fh:
    try:
        raise ValueError("Some error occurred")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e, file=fh)
```

`cat my_errors.txt`

```
Some error occurred
```

Note that `logging.exception` *includes* the traceback in this case, which is one of the many huge benefits of that module

### Edit

In the interest of completeness, the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module leverages a similar approach as `print`, where you can supply a file handle:

```py
import traceback
import sys

with open('error.txt', 'a') as fh:
    try:
        raise ValueError("Some error occurred")
    except ValueError as e:
        e_type, e_val, e_tb = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_exception(e_type, e_val, e_tb, file=fh)
```

This will include all of the information you want from `logging`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `logging` module as suggested in the comments (possibly superior but outside the scope of my knowledge), or catch the errors with `try` and `except` like:

```
try:
    pass
    #run the code you currently have
except Exception as e: # catch ALLLLLL errors!!!
    print(e) # or more likely you'd want something like "email_to_me(e)"
```

Although this is generally frowned upon to catch **all** exceptions, because then should your program fail for *whatever* reason it will get gobbled up in the `except` clause so a better approach is to figure out what specific error you are encountering like `IndexError` and then just catch this specific error like:

```
try:
    pass
    #run the code you currently have
except IndexError as e: # catch only indexing errors!!!
    print(e) # or more likely you'd want something like "email_to_me(e)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Logging is hard for me at the moment, I will look into it in the near future

Comment: @strangethingspy No problem! If this solved your problem it's common practice to click the check mark by my post to accept it as the answer you were looking for! When you get 15 rep you can upvote helpful answers (and questions) as well :)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to debug and not only know the kind of error that happened, you can also get the error stack using traceback module (usually in the starting package of modules):

```
import traceback
try:
    my_function()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    traceback.print_exc()
```

And then run your code 'my_code.py' in console usig >>

```
python my_code.py >> my_prints.txt
```

All the prints of your code will then be written in this .txt file, including the printed error and its stack. This is very interesting in your case or while running code on a docker if you want to detach yourself from it with ctrl+p+q and still know what is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily log console error messages into text file with this command

```
import sys
import logging

# Create a logging instance
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    filename='errors.log', filemode='w')


def raise_error():
    a = []
    try:
        # This will raise an IndexError exception
        print(a[1])
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error to the file
        logging.error('An error occurred:', exc_info=True)


# Call the function that raises an error
raise_error()
```