# How to print python console error in my log file

Tags: python

This is my code printing logs also. If you will replace (1,0,-4) with (1,0,1) at the bottom of page, you will get an valueerror. So, I want to print this error in my mathslog.txt file ,how to do it?
Code is starting from here:

```
import logging
import math


LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="E:\\logs\\mathslogs.log", level= logging.DEBUG, filemode='w',format= LOG_FORMAT ,datefmt= '%y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p')


logger = logging.getLogger()


def quadraticc_formula(a,b,c):
    """Return the solutions to the equation ax^2 + bx + c=0."""
    
    logger.info("Calculating quadratic_formula for values ({0},{1},{2})".format(a,b,c))
    
    #Compute the discrminant
    logger.debug("#Compute the discriminant")
    disc = b**2 - 4*a*c
    
    # Compute the two roots
    logger.debug("Compute the two roots")
    root1 = (-b + math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a)
    root2 = (-b - math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a)
    
    #Return the roots
    logger.debug("#Successfully Calculated")

    
    
    return (root1,root2)
   

roots = quadraticc_formula(1,0,-4)
print(roots)
```

Comment: Please refer to this page. This will give your answer. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169364/python-how-to-write-error-in-the-console-in-txt-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to write error in the console in txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169364/python-how-to-write-error-in-the-console-in-txt-file)

Answer (score 2):

you can write this in log file also,by using exception to log.

```
try:
   roots = quadraticc_formula(1,0,-4) print(roots)
except Exception as msg:
   log.error(msg)     #writes in log file
```

Comment: Already >>>logging.basicConfig(filename="E:\logs\mathslogs.log"<<< this step is done. So no need to again open a file and write. Automatically log.error will right inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, if you want to catch *all uncaught* exceptions in your logger, is to take advantage of `sys` module's `excepthook`. Doing this once will make all exceptions go through your logger. This leaves freedom for you to use `try` `except` blocks that actually make more sense programmatically.

```py
# set the excepthook to route through your logger before you call quadraticc_formula
sys.excepthook = lambda type, value, tb: logger.exception(value)
```

Here's a link to a more thorough discussion:
[Using python's logging module to log all exceptions and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050775/using-pythons-logging-module-to-log-all-exceptions-and-errors)